# Equivalence Principle in Newtonian Physics vs GR: A Thought Experiment

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, time-dilation, equivalence-principle

I have a question regarding the equivalence principle as it applies in Newtonian Physics and General Relativity. Consider a thought experiment involving a free-falling elevator.

Inside the elevator, there are two extremely accurate clocks: one at the top and one at the bottom. These clocks are connected via wires to a tool that compares the time displayed by each clock. This tool is in the hand of an observer inside the elevator.
Newtonian Physics:

According to Newtonian physics, both clocks should tick at the same rate, regardless of whether the elevator is in free fall or in a state of weightlessness. The tool comparing the times should show no discrepancy between the two clocks.
General Relativity:

However, according to GR, and considering the effects of gravitational time dilation, would there be any asynchrony between the two clocks? Assume that the clocks are capable of measuring extremely tiny fractions of a second and that the elevator falls for a sufficient duration to detect any discrepancy.

Questions:

1. Would there be a time discrepancy between the two clocks according to GR?
2. If there is a discrepancy in GR, does it imply that Newtonian physics in some cases better satisfies the conditions of the equivalence principle than GR does?

I appreciate any answers and clarifications on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to note that the equivalence principle is only *locally* true, i.e. in a small enough region of spacetime, and establishes an equivalence between acceleration and a *uniform* gravitational field. In the real world no gravitational field is uniform (they vary by distance) and so with sensitive enough clocks yes, you could determine whether or not your elevator is in a gravitational field. The smaller the elevator, the more sensitive the clocks you would need.

Gravitational time dilation is very well established experimentally (modern atomic clocks can detect a one meter difference in height based on the rate of passage of time alone), so in that regard Newtonian gravity is simply a non-starter: it's experimentally disproven.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to precise that the word "locally or small enough" means an *infinitely small* region of spacetime.

Comment: Eric, thank you for your answer. In the question, I asked mostly not on its correspondence to the reality (it's experimentally proven or disproven) but its correspondence to the equivalence principle as such. So, it means GR satisfies the equivalence principle only locally, but Newton physics (even not describing the reality) satisfies the equivalence principle locally and also non-locally?

Comment: Actually even Newtonian gravity doesn't satisfy the equivalence principle, because of the acceleration due to gravity will be slightly different at the top and bottom of the free falling elevator and this will give rise to tidal forces.

Comment: Moreover Newtonian physics never satisfies the equivalence principle for a simpler reason. Just imagine your observer has a laser pointer. In Newtonian physics the trajectory of the laser light will not be consistent with the equivalence principle, even in a very small region.

Comment: Uniform field = no tidal forces. Small enough region of spacetime = tidal forces small enough. Equivalence principle applies perfectly if uniform field. Equivalence principle applies well enough if small enough region of spacetime.

Answer (score 0):

The person that says that there is an asynchrony between the clocks also says that there is an asymmetry between up- and down- directions, and that asymmetry has the effect that the asynchrony of the clocks is not detected inside the elevator.

As an example, the aforementioned person might say that there is an increasing asynchrony between the clocks because of increasing gravitational time dilation difference between clocks, and also because of increasing velocity time dilation difference between clocks. Said velocity time dilation difference is caused by lower clock moving faster than the upper clock, as measured by said person by comparing the speed of clocks to speed of a light pulses near the clocks.

Then the aforementioned person continues: If the distance between the clocks is very small, then the light leaving the lower clock is Doppler-shifted because of the motion of the lower clock, and the light received by the upper clock is Doppler-shifted because of the motion of the upper clock. Now if those Doppler-shifts are almost synchronous, like when the distance between the clocks is very small, then the Doppler-shifts almost cancel out each other. So increasing the asynhcrony of the Doppler-shifts by increasing the distance between the clocks causes an increasing Doppler-shift. Said increasing Doppler-shift cancels out the asynchorony of the clocks. (The person that says that there is an asynchrony of clocks says that a person inside the elevator does not detect said asynchrony because of the Doppler-shift.)

There is an asymmetry of time dilation effects of clocks being moved inside the elevator, caused by the asymmetry of the elevator's direction of motion, and the the non-linearity of the time dilation formula. This asymmetry of time dilation effects causes the clocks' readings to be the same when the clocks are moved to the same position.

Answer (score 0):

1.Yes there will be a time discrepancy. Assume we have a spherically symmetric gravitational field. Assuming an observer at rest with respect to the gravitational field placed infinitely far away. During a very short time interval this observer records the time $\Delta t_i$ on his clock.

We can assume that the "top clock" of the elevator is located at a radial distance from the center of the gravitational field of $r_t$ and the "bottom clock" of radial distance $r_b$. During the time interval $\Delta t_i$ the top clock will record the time:

$$\Delta t_t=\Delta t_i{\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r_tc^2}-\frac{v^2}{c^2\left((1-\frac{2GM}{r_tc^2})(\hat{r_t}\cdot\hat{v})^2+|\hat{r_t}\times\hat{v}|^2\right)}}}\tag{1}$$

while the bottom clock will record the time:

$$\Delta t_b=\Delta t_i{\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r_bc^2}-\frac{v^2}{c^2\left((1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2})(\hat{r_b}\cdot\hat{v})^2+|\hat{r_b}\times\hat{v}|^2\right)}}}\tag{2}$$

($\hat{r_b},\hat{r_t},\hat{v}$ unit vectors)

As is seen so long as $r_t \neq r_b$ the time recorded at the top of the elevator and at the bottom of the elevator will typically not  be the same even if they travel with the same velocity.

If the motion is purely radial, as in the case of a free falling elevator, these expressions reduce to:

$$\Delta t_t=\Delta t_i{\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r_tc^2}-\frac{v^2}{c^2\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r_tc^2}\right)}}}\tag{3}$$

$$\Delta t_b=\Delta t_i{\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r_bc^2}-\frac{v^2}{c^2\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r_bc^2}\right)}}}\tag{4}$$

The velocity in these expressions are the velocity as interpreted by an observer at rest at infinity. Whether the elevator is accelerating or not does not really matters. What matters for an individual clock is the gravitational potential and the velocity (including direction) of the clock.